# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError when loading json file in Python

Tags: python, json

I am getting the following error when I try to load a JSON file in Python
Here's my code:

```
import json
data = json.load(open('original.json'))
print(data["smog"])
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error:json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 1534083 (char 1534082)
```

What should I do?

Comment: can you show us bytes 1534050 through 1534100 of the contents of `original.json`?  That's there the trouble is.

Comment: Let me add a note for your next question: Stack Overflow is great because users (you and me!) post comprehensive questions and answers. To make your question easier to answer please also describe what you have tried and where you got the JSON file from.
Besides, SO supports [Markdown formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for code and terminal output.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON file seems to either be corrupt or have an unexpected format: `Invalid control character at: line 1 column 1534083`

Did you maybe open/edit it with a text editor after downloading?

Apart from that it seems to be a pretty big file. Better start with something very simple and verify that your code works with that first, for example:

```
{
    myProperty: "my value"
}
```

Comment: Its working for small json files but I want this json file to be worked

Comment: Then you need to check which character there is at `line 1 column 1534083`. Apparently the file is not properly formatted. It would also help if you could provide the file (and where you got it from) so that others can take a look, too.

Comment: when i downloaded it when i tried to open it viewed in a single instead of many lines

Comment: Indeed, that is why the invalid character is on line 1 but the column index is huuuge. My previous comment still applies though: Please show us the file and find out which character is at the specified location.

Comment: how to share a file here?

Comment: You mentioned earlier that you downloaded the file from the internet. The easiest way would be to post the link to the file here.

Comment: i downloaded it from udemy i cannot find link